# ControllerActionInvoker

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, controlleractioninvoker

What is the use of ControllerActionInvoker class?

Comment: take look http://www.olivieralbertini.com/Tutorial/asp-net-mvc-partial-view-action-invoker-jquery-ui-ajax. It's a tutorial with a demo. I hope that will help you

Answer (score 14):

Basically it's an extensibility point on a Controller class that allows you to get in there and influence how the controller interacts with Parameters, Filters and the Action itself. When a request has been routed to the Controller, the Controller asks the ControllerActionInvoker to deal with the request (which normally involves it calling a method back on the Controller).

The main usage of this I've seen so far is to provide dependency injection into Action Filters as shown [here](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/05/03/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-mvc-filters/), but I'm sure we'll see more uses for this feature popping up in the future!

Comment: The link is dead. :-(